# Select * from table where date = today

Tags: php, mysql

Need help with PHP/MySql. Need to select all the records from 'today'.

My table has a coloumn which holds a unixtime stamp and I want to just select from the table where the unixtime stamp = today.

Happy to do this on linux command line just need to basic MySql query?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'd go for the SQL version:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE(timestamp_field) = CURDATE();`

Comment: use DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp_field)) if timestamp_field holds the no. of seconds since 1970

Comment: +1 Though I would also use `CURDATE()` or `CURRENT_DATE` instead of `DATE(NOW())`

Comment: There - I fixed it - now it use CURDATE() :-)

Comment: Expression over the field rules out the possible usage of indexes.

Answer (score 3):

Since you tagged PHP I'll provide a PHP answer:

```
list ( $y, $m, $d ) = explode('.', date('Y.m.d')); 
$today_start = mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, $d, $y);
$today_end   = mktime(23, 59, 59, $m, $d, $y);
// do the query with this clause:
// ... WHERE unix_timestamp BETWEEN $today_start AND $today_end
```

Comment: you have to encapsulate your date string in `'` or `"` like `date('Y.m.d')`

Answer (score 3):

Here are the **proper** ways of doing that:

```
WHERE `date` BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(NOW())) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), 1 DAY)))
```

if there is no values in the future (tomorrow, 2 days after tomorrow, etc) then it can be simplified to:

```
WHERE `date` >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(NOW()))
```

and when you change your `date` field type to `datetime` the possible query will be:

```
WHERE `date` >= DATE(NOW())
```

When I say "proper" I mean that these queries **can be** optimized by using indexes. And queries like `DATE(order_time) = DATE(NOW())` - cannot, because it is an expression over the field.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE DATE(date) = DATE(NOW())
```

Answer (score 1):

A suitable WHERE clause might be:

```
CAST( FROM_UNIXTIME( <your_field> ) AS DATE ) = CURDATE( )
```

- [FROM_UNIXTIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)( ) - converts to MySQL DATETIME
- CAST( AS DATE ) - gets just the date part
- CURDATE( ) - gets the current date

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE date >= CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$q="select * from table where date >'".date("Y-m-d 00:00:00")."' and date <'".date("Y-m-d 23:59:59")."'";
```

Answer (score 1):

on my table that has a datetime column, I use this successfully

```
 SELECT * FROM orders WHERE DATE(order_time) = DATE(NOW())
```