# select all where date = today?

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Select * from table where date = today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838166/select-from-table-where-date-today)

Hello, I am trying to do a mysql query to get all the rows where date = "today".....

The problem is, I store my downloads date using timestamp like $date = time();

I would like to get away from using the unix timestamp and start using the correct mysql field type as well instead of just text, can anyone help me out?

I would like a better way to store dates and then also if you can provide me with a mysql_query to select all entries that have been added today.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Sebastian P.: and highest scored answers there are just terrible (since they cannot be optimized)

Comment: Guys, don't close this with reference to that question!!! If you want to close this - please find one with better answers!

Comment: @zerkms: All the more reason to provide a better answer to that question, then, isn't it? The content of the question is more or less the same. If the answers aren't satisfactory, then post a satisfactory answer, and the answer will rise to the top. No need to duplicate the question for that.

Comment: @Sebastian P.: I cannot find a better, but that one has weird answers. I ask a community to not close with reference to that Q.

Comment: @Sebastian P.: added my answer there too...

Comment: @zerkms: Flagging as duplicate has nothing to do with the quality of the answers posted thus far. If you feel the other question hasn't been answered properly, post a better answer. The best answer can change over time. Having duplicates of question means it's more likely that some of the duplicates will have worse answers than others. Therefore I don't find the lack of a good answer on the other question a valid excuse for not closing this one.

Comment: @Sebastian P.: ok, it's your wish as a highly-reputated user, who has tools to moderate content here. I respect your wish even though I still don't agree with it ;-)

Answer (score 4):

```
WHERE `date` BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(NOW())) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), 1 DAY)))
```

if there is no values in the future (tomorrow, 2 days after tomorrow, etc) then it can be simplified to:

```
WHERE `date` >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(NOW()))
```

and when you change your `date` field type to `datetime` the possible query will be:

```
WHERE `date` >= DATE(NOW())
```

Comment: Will this work in php? I am trying to get the syntax working.

Comment: @user607421: The answer is purely SQL code, it will work regardless of what scripting language you are using.

Comment: @user607421: this is a part of sql query, which will work in any programming language

Comment: Thank you for the help so far, I am trying to get this to work in my php script but can't get it working without errors (syntax related), can one of you provide me with a simple mysql_query() code to give me an example? Thanks so much.

Comment: @user607421: it is not the correct way to act here. If you have an issues with **your code** - put it in the question with the corresponding error and get a help.

Comment: Oh lol sorry I didn't know what the high etiquette standards, I will ask another question, thanks.

Comment: @user607421: it is not "etiquette" ;-) It is just a better way for you to learn ;-) I hope you're here to become better programmer, but not the one who just copy-paste the complete solutions.

Comment: Thanks Zerkms, with some playing around I got it to work!